# Can I have an exponential function such that if x = infinity, y = 100?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I tried the most basic y = 100*constant^(1/x) assuming that 1/x = 0 when x is infinity, but it doesn't seem to work.

This gives me a function that starts with a higher value of y and goes down till it reaches 100 at the value of infinity. But I want a rising value of y that reaches 100 only at infinity, and remains below 100 the rest of the time.

Answer (score 3):

How about $f(x) = 100 + e^{-x}$? It has a limit of $100$ as $x\to\infty$ (by the way, it is better to speak of *limits* as $x$ *approaches* infinity, rather than being equal to it.

Comment: Will try it out and see if it works in my program. Now assuming I want to vary it with a constant, can I just make it e^(-cx)?

Comment: Rather $100-e^{-x}$. (Or perhaps $100(1-e^{-x})$.)

Comment: as $x\to\infty$, $e^cx$ will have a limit of $0$ if $c>0$ and $0$ if $c<0$, so the answer to your question will be no.

Comment: @TonyK $100-e^{-x}$ has the same limit as $100+e^{-x}$, both have a limit of $100$.

Comment: Tried all suggestions, it doesn't seem to work. It just seems to return a value of 100. For y = 100 - e^-x. 
This is when x = 100.

Comment: @5xum, the OP asks for an increasing function.

Comment: "It just seems to return a value of 100." Is't that what you need?!